# r package or wrapper to handle ta-lib

Tags: python, r

I am trying to do some technical analysis work and build some automated trading algos. After some extensive research, ta-lib seems to be the most complete technical indicators library available out there (www.ta-lib.org). However, no matter how much i search i am unable to find an R package or wrapper that allows me to use it in R.

There is a python wrapper for it but, despite all my searching, I am unable to find it for R. I would really like to be able to call the TA-Lib functions from RStudio. Does anyone know where I can find an R wrapper or any other alternative?

Many thanks.
Claudio

Answer (score 1):

You could use the R [r-python](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/index.html) package to wrap your calls in python calls, you may have to provide a small python wrapper to import and initialize the library and possibly to provide an abstraction layer for the library calls.

Comment: That's one way to go. Thanks for the suggestion. My fear os that calling a python wrapper from inside R is not a "clean" solution and might end up being too slow. I was really hoping that someone would know some R native code/solution....

Comment: I did find some discussion of an effort to generate an R wrapper 5 years ago but it seems it was a bit of a one man show.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. Alternatively, are you aware of any extensive r package for technical analysis? I'm specifically more interested in candles pattern recognition.

Comment: http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/candlesticks/html/candlesticks-package.html any good?

Comment: That was the only one i found as well. Downside is that its library is much smaller than ta-lib. Ie, only a few of the common patterns are there. I guess i'll have to use that if nothing else comes up. Alternatively, will look into calling python from R and stick to ta-lib (added advantage being that i know it well and am comfortable with it).

Comment: If speed is an issue you could put the majority of the code in python and use a Python R wrapper. RPy http://rpy.sourceforge.net or RSPython http://www.omegahat.org/RSPython that should resolve any speed issues.

Comment: Brilliant. Will give it a go.